# WP get_posts showinn only 5 results. (nopaging, posts_per_page and numberposts not working)

Tags: wordpress

I have this piece of code which works but it's showing only 5 posts (with custom taxonomy) where should be 7. If I hit the tag url, it shows the 7 registries, so the problem it's in this code and its query. I already tried nopaging = true, posts_per_page = -1 numberposts = -1 and setting the last two to fixed numbers, like 7 or 999; but none of this options seem to do the trick.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks.

```
add_shortcode('gpp_prod', function( $atts, $content = null ){
ob_start();

$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'category' => '0'
    ), $atts);

extract($atts);

$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'gpp_prod',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

if($category > 0 ){
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'taxonomy' => 'cat_prod',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'nopaging' => true,
            'terms' => $category
        )
    );
}

?>
<?php $products = get_posts($args);
$termt = get_term($category, 'cat_prod');

<div class="prod-cats">
    <h1><?php echo $termt->name;?></h1>
    <?php if(count($products)>0) {
        foreach ($products as $key => $value) { ?>
        <div class="prod-group">
            <div class="prod-title"><?php echo do_shortcode( $value->post_title); ?></div>
            <div class="prod-low">
                <div class="prod-image"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($value->ID)); ?>"/></div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="prod-info">
                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab-1-<?php echo $value->ID?>" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Desc</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab-2-<?php echo $value->ID?>" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Specs</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab-1-<?php echo $value->ID?>"><?php echo do_shortcode( $value->post_content); ?></div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab-2-<?php echo $value->ID?>"><?php $meta_value = get_post_meta( $value->ID, 'meta-text', false );
                                               if( !empty( $meta_value ) ) {
                                                   echo $meta_value[0];
                                               } else {
                                                   echo 'No specs available';
                                               }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
<?php
wp_reset_postdata();
return ob_get_clean();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

posts_per_page needs to go in your $args array, not in $args['tax_query'].  Also nopaging is redundant when setting posts_per_page = -1.  Try this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'gpp_prod',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

if($category > 0 ){
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'cat_prod',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $category
        )
    );
}
```